# How to change permissions of a docker mounted volume on OSX to work with Nginx web server running Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, macos, laravel, nginx, docker

I am using Docker running Laravel 5.1 to generate PDFs so my problem is the file gets generated successfully without errors and is saved to the mounted volume. The problem arises when i try to pull the file back to display it using `Storage::disk('local')->get($filename);` I get

```
ErrorException in Local.php line 187:
file_put_contents(/app/storage/app/savedfile.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied.
```

I also tried changing the permissions from inside the docker container, and also manually on the mounted volume, it did not help.

Here is the code i used to save the file

```
    $snappy = new Pdf('wkhtmltopdf');
    $tmpFile = storage_path().'/app/savedfile.pdf';

    $snappy->setOption('images', true);
    $snappy->setOption('footer-right', '[page] OF [topage]');

    $result = $snappy->generateFromHtml(
        $view->render(),
        $tmpFile
    );

    Storage::disk('local')->put('report.pdf',  \File::get($tmpFile));
```

Does anyone know how i can resolve this?

Comment: Please, show the code

Comment: @LubošTurek, thanks for that i edited the question to include the code

Comment: What command do you use to run laravel in docker and to get the file back using docker?

Comment: @michalkralik i am not using a command to run laravel in docker, i let nginx deal with it. also im am using laravel to get the file back, and not docker

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question then. You say you can't pull a file back, but the error says you can't save the file. Also do you try to pull the file back from the same container or is it outside docker?

Comment: @michalkralik i am using the above code to save the file to my projects' directory which is a mounted volume on my docker container, i investigated and found that the error arrises because docker uses lxc containers which run linux, and linux has users "user, roor and www-data" but since the folder is mounted on OSX which has users "user, staff and everyone" and these users dont match across the two operating sysytems.

Comment: @michalkralik would you advice that i create an equivalent user on my mac OSX, whose permissions will match those of my Docker user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while to try and fix this, but when docker for mac was anounced i quickly moved to it, i havent had permission issues since.

So i recommend you checkout [Docker For Mac](https://www.docker.com/docker-mac)

Answer (score 1):

Docker users are not the same as the host machine's.
You need to make sure that the host machine's user and container's user that access the mounted volume have both access to the volume's files.

You can achieve this in a couple ways, for example:

1. Make the files world readable/writable
2. Make sure the user ID of both host computer and container is the same
3. Change permissions of the file after it's written

After you make the change you should be able to read/write the pdf files.

Comment: i am going to try this and get back to you, thanks for the response

Comment: Ran into a similar issue, any luck?

Comment: @michal kralik, how would you change the user id of the docker container to match the host computer?

Comment: @Philll_t there are couple ways - the easiest is to check what the ID of the user on your host computer is and then after a file is saved from within the docker container, you just `chown ID file`. This way the file is owned by the ID of the user on host computer and the file can be accessed without root on host computer.